# Switch to my AMD RADEON graphics Topaz XT in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics

In **About this Computer** I see:

Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)

But I have got hybrid graphics. I have external `AMD Radeon TOPAZ XT` graphics card. How can I make it work in my `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`.

I am trying to use VGA Switcheroo, can someone tell me what commands should I add so as to make the dedicated graphics work?

Also I tried to install `amdgpu-pro` graphics driver but it made my screen go blank. So I had to uninstall it.

Answer (score -1):

Open up Synaptic package manager and install the `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` package. Reboot your computer. You should automatically be switched to your Radeon card, however, you should check your additional drivers menu to be sure the switch was made.